# Model instance method returning wrong result the first time it is run, and the correct result subsequently

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models, related with has_many :through associations:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :account_owners
  has_many :employees, through: account_owners

  def is_owned_or_belongs_to_team_of_employees(employee)
    employee.team.any? { |m| employees.include?(m) }
  end
end

class AccountOwner < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :employee
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :account_owners
  has_many :accounts, through: :account_owners

  def team
    self.class.where(
      'id IN (?)',
      self. class.find_by_sql(['WITH RECURSIVE search_tree(id, path) AS (
                                  SELECT id, ARRAY[id]
                                    FROM employees
                                    WHERE id = ?
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT employees.id, path || employees.id
                                    FROM search_tree
                                    JOIN employees ON employees.manager_id = search_tree.id
                                    WHERE NOT employees.id = ANY(path)
                                )
                                SELECT id FROM search_tree ORDER BY path',
                             self.id])
    ).order(:id)
  end
end
```

I'm manually testing, in the Rails console in my development environment (using some fixtures that I first loaded on the database), the `Account#is_owned_or_belongs_to_team_of_employees` method.

When I run the method in the console this is what happens:

```
> a = Account.first
 => #<Account id: 534788375, name: "Sales Rep 1 (elena)-owned account", code: "EEE", created_at: "2018-07-15 09:41:55", updated_at: "2018-07-15 09:41:55">
> e = Employee.find_by(first_name: 'Elena')
 => #<Employee id: 701979064, first_name: "Elena", last_name: "López", manager_id: 1069403509, created_at: "2018-07-15 09:41:55", updated_at: "2018-07-15 09:41:55", mobile: nil, work: nil>
> e.team
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Employee id: 701979064, first_name: "Elena", last_name: "López", manager_id: 1069403509, created_at: "2018-07-15 09:41:55", updated_at: "2018-07-15 09:41:55", mobile: nil, work: nil>]>
> a.is_owned_or_belongs_to_team_of e
 => nil
> a.is_owned_or_belongs_to_team_of e
 => true
```

As you can see, the method returns `nil` (wrong!) the first time, and returns `true` (correct!) the following times.

The amazing thing is that I can correct the problem if I define the method like this:

```
def is_owned_or_belongs_to_team_of employee
  puts "employees are #{employees.inspect}"
  employee.team.any? { |m| employees.include?(m) }
end
```

Now the execution is correct, and the method returns consistently the same result (`true` in my example):

```
> a = Account.first
 => #<Account id: 534788375, name: "Sales Rep 1 (elena)-owned account", code: "EEE", created_at: "2018-07-15 09:41:55", updated_at: "2018-07-15 09:41:55">
> e = Employee.find_by(first_name: 'Elena')
 => #<Employee id: 701979064, first_name: "Elena", last_name: "López", manager_id: 1069403509, created_at: "2018-07-15 09:41:55", updated_at: "2018-07-15 09:41:55", mobile: nil, work: nil>
> e.team
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Employee id: 701979064, first_name: "Elena", last_name: "López", manager_id: 1069403509, created_at: "2018-07-15 09:41:55", updated_at: "2018-07-15 09:41:55", mobile: nil, work: nil>]>
> a.is_owned_or_belongs_to_team_of e
 => true
> a.is_owned_or_belongs_to_team_of e
 => true
```

If I remove the `puts` statement, we are back to square one: the method returns `nil` the first time, and `true` the following times.

And, amazingly, if I keep the `puts` statement but remove the `inspect` (that is, I just do `puts "employees are #{employees}"` we are also back to square one: `nil` the first time, and `true` the following times.

Any idea? What is going on here?

By the way, I'm running Ruby 2.5.1 y Rails 5.2.0.

Comment: I also noticed this behavior, inspect seems to trigger the query execution after the object is instantiated.

Comment: SQL used in `team` method is very complex, can you share its output. Just the results of `puts "#{employee.team}"`.

Comment: `is_owned_or_belongs_to_team_of` can be written as: `(employee.team & employees).present?`

Comment: @AtulVaibhav, I just edited the question to add the results of e.team. Thanks for your suggestion on changing the method code, I'll check if it is better - though in any case I would love to know why what I original wrote is not working correctly the first time.

Comment: Although I can't really find documentation for it but you could also fix it via ```    ).order(:id)``` and change it to ```).order(:id).all``` in the last line of ```def team```. It has something to do with how active record relations are resolved. When you check https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L226 you can see that it return just the relation instead of doing the empty check. I am still unsure why the second run then works.

Comment: If you want to understand exactly what is happening, I highly recommend you to debug your code using the byebug gem, this way, you will be able to understand the state of each variable at each step, and more importantly, understand when the queries are launched.

Comment: There is something worth noting, there are 2 `any?` methods that can be called on your object. `any?` of ActiveRecord::Relation and `any?` of Array, and neither of them can return something else than true or false. I really cannot understand how these methods could return `nil`...  Are you sure there are no information you forgot to put in your question ?

Comment: I created the same situation in my dummy app and it's working perfectly, returning true or false at first call, with no need of the `.inspect` line. Using `gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'`,  `'pg', '~> 0.18.4'`, `ruby '2.4.1'`, Maybe you can specify the database in use adding also the related tag. Please fix `has_many :employees, through: account_owners` adding colon before `account_owners`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm glad I stumbled upon this Unicorn of a bug!

After debugging this for hours, I found out the following:

1. `any?` had new changes in [rails 5.2 release](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/b644964b2b555798fc4b94d384b98438db863b3f#diff-eb992cfe9de67b368e9d3736ab1388d8R285) that was supposed to delegate it to `Enumerable`
2. the surprising thing, that if you put a binding.pry in the implementation of `any?` and call `super` it returns true even the first time and then the method returns `nil`. `~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb @ line 228 ActiveRecord::Relation#any?:`
3. if you add to `employee.team` `.to_a` everything works consistently.
4. if you put `any? { |_| true }` it returns true.
5. If you check for the value inside the block for `include?` it returns true but `any?` still returns `nil`!!!
6. If you avoid resolving the `has_may through` association (by calling `.to_a` before the block) or even using a different association inside the `any?` block everything works as expected.
7. using any other ruby version fixes the problem.

### Summary

The problem was introduced in ruby `2.5.1` rails `v5.2.0` when `ActiveRecord::Relation` started to include `Enumerable`.It happens with `%w(none? any? one? many?)` while trying to resolve a `has many through` association in its block.

Comment: have you filed a bug with Rails? It would be nice to get confirmation that it is, indeed, a bug.

Comment: Not yet, will file it this weekend though.